# Can printf take a floating point variable as an argument for a %d format specifier?

Tags: c, printf

So, my question is, when I try to use %d as a format specifier and print 'a', which is a floating value, I get the answer as 0. I want to know why that is so.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    float a = 3.5;
    clrscr();
    printf("The value of a is:%d",a);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is not standard C, and mismatching printf conversion specifiers to argument types means your program has undefined behavior. Anything can happen. Printing 0 is the least problematic thing that could happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` specifier only takes integers. To format floating point numbers use `%f`.

See the [printf manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?printf(3)) on how to choose which format specifier you should use for which input.